# Query regarding writing to channel via netty through multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, netty

Consider this method from one of my handlers at server side

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

    try {
        io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush("Executing command now...");
        System.out.println("command execution future - " + f);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            int i = 4;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(i >= 0 ) {
                    io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush("beat till command");
                    System.out.println("beat till command future - " + f);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(6*1000);
                        i--;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }).start();

        //assume some processing here
        Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
}
```

In above code when I write to channel in same thread it is immediately sent to the client, i.e. this message `ctx.writeAndFlush("Executing command now...")` is sent immediately

But when I try the same thing from a different thread, it is not sent immediately( `ctx.writeAndFlush("beat till command")` ). Also the future `DefaultChannelPromise@5aa824c(incomplete)` shows that the operation is incomplete. All these calls are deferred I guess and are completed once the main thread is done. Why is that so? Some locks on ctx?

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Only writes from the netty threads are instant on the channel, for thead-safety reasons

Comment: instead of  new Thread(new Runnable() ... use `ctx.channel().eventLoop().submit( ...`

Comment: thanks & +1 Ferrybig & rkosegi. I found that the problem can also be addressed in a different way if I provide this handler a different EventExecutor. Actually this handler had blocked my I/O thread because of which my HeartBeatHandler was unable to send heartbeats till this very handler continues to execute.